# Distinct or unique count for a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, distinct

I found similar answers but not the way I need it.

Data

```
data = {'Column1':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,], 
        'Column2':['A','A','A','C','B','A','C','C','B','D','D','E','F'],
        'Column3':['True','False','True','False','True','False','True','False','True','False','False','True','False']}

table = pd.DataFrame(data)

    Column1 Column2 Column3
0         1       A    True
1         2       A   False
2         3       A    True
3         4       C   False
4         5       B    True
5         6       A   False
6         7       C    True
7         8       C   False
8         9       B    True
9        10       D   False
10       11       D   False
11       12       E    True
12       13       F   False
```

Group by

```
Cols = ['Column3']

table1 = table.groupby(Cols ).agg(['sum']).reset_index()

  Column3 Column1  Column2
              sum      sum
0   False      54  ACACDDF
1    True      37   AABCBE
```

So far so good, but what I also need is a unique or distinct count for Column2. So the output should look as the one below.

```
  Column3 Column1  Column2
              sum  distinct
0   False      54        4
1    True      37        4
```

I tried .unique(), .nunique(), but it gives me the unique value for the whole columns, but individual ones. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: `table.groupby(Cols, as_index=False).agg({'Column1': ['sum'], 'Column2': ['nunique']})`. (Note that you don't need to wrap the function name in a list).

Comment: Perfect. Another questions with this part, 'Column1': ['sum']. If I have multiple Columns similar to column1, how to I put this part. I want to avoid, 'Column1': ['sum'], 'Column10': ['sum'], 'Column1'1: ['sum'].
Ideally something like Sum = ['Column1','Column10','Column11']
Sum: ['sum'].

Comment: Please [edit] the question, code/data as comment is unfortunately not intelligible.

Comment: Perfect. Another questions with this part, ```.agg({'Column1': ['sum']```. If I have multiple Columns similar to column1, how to I put this part. I want to avoid, ```.agg({'Column1': ['sum'], 'Column10': ['sum'], 'Column1'1: ['sum'], ...```
Ideally something like ```Sum = ['Column1','Column10','Column11']``` and then ```.agg({Sum: ['sum'], ...```

Comment: I meant [edit] (click on the link) ;) That will make it a more interesting question which can be reopened to have actual answers